# How to setup equation that involves a sum from x=1 to infinity and loops?

Tags: matlab

I am getting confused on how to properly set up this equation. To find a value of V(i,j). The end result would be plotting V over time. I understand that there needs to be loops to allow this equation to work, however I am lost when it comes to setting it up. Basically I am trying to take the sum from n=1 to infinity of `(1-(-1)^n)/(n^4 *pi^4)*sin((n*pi*c*j)/L)*sin((n*pi*i)/L)` 
I originally thought that I should make it a while loop to increment n by 1 until I reach say 10 or so just to get an idea of what the output would look like. All of the variables were unknown and values were added again to see what the plot would look like. 
I have down another code where the equation is just dependent on i and j. However with this n term, I am thrown off. Any advice would be great as to setting up the equation. Thank you.

```
L=10;
x=linspace(0,L,30);
t1= 50;
X=30;
p=1
c=t1/1000;
V=zeros(X,t1);
V(1,:)=0;
V(30,:)=0;
R=((4*p*L^3)/c);
n=1;
t=1:50;
while n < 10
    for i=1:31
     for j=1:50
         V(i,j)=R*sum((1-(-1)^n)/(n^4 *pi^4)*sin((n*pi*c*j)/L)*sin((n*pi*i)/L));
     end
    end
    n=n+1;
end


figure(1)
plot(V(i,j),t)
```

Comment: `V(i,j)` has size (1,1) while `t` is a vector (1,50). What are you trying to plot? Also, if you want the sum over `n`, you need to do something like `V(i,j)=V(i,j)+...` to sum the preceding value with current one and so on. As it is, your code sums only one value if I understand correctly. Thus, `sum()` is not doing anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Various ways of doing so:

1) Computing the sum up to one `Nmax` in one shot:

```
Nmax = 30;
Vijn = @(i,j,n) R*((1-(-1)^n)/(n^4 *pi^4)*sin((n*pi*c*j)/L)*sin((n*pi*i)/L));
i = 1:31;
j = 1:50;
n = 1:Nmax;
[I,J,N] = ndgrid(i,j,n);
V = arrayfun(Vijn,I,J,N);
Vc = cumsum(V,3);
% now Vc(:,:,k) is sum_n=1^{k+1} V(i,j,n)

figure(1);clf;imagesc(Vc(:,:,end));
```

2) Looping indefinitely

```
n = 1;
V = 0;
i = 1:31;
j = 1:50;
[I,J] = meshgrid(i,j);
while true
    V = V + R*((1-(-1)^n)/(n^4 *pi^4)*sin((n*pi*c*J)/L).*sin((n*pi*I)/L));
    n = n + 1;      
    figure(1);clf;
    imagesc(V);
    title(sprintf('N = %d',n))
    drawnow;
    pause(0.25);
end
```

Note that in your example you won't need many terms, since:

- Every second term is zero (for even `n`, the term `1-(-1)^n` is zero).
- The terms decay with `1/n^4`. In norms: `n=1` contributes ~2e4, `n=3` contributes ~4e2, `n=5` contributes 5e1, `n=7` contributes ~14, etc. Visually, there is a small  difference between `n=1` and `n=1`+`n=3` but barely a noticeable one for `n=1`+`n=3`+`n=5`.
- Given that so few terms are needed, the first approach is probably the better one. Also, skip the even indices, as you don't need them.

Comment: Thank you very much @Florian for explaining it. I am going to take a look at arrayfun and ndgrid as I have not used those before and then try implementing it!